# Retrieve Events from Google Calendar Using API

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am a complete newbie with Google Calendar API and PHP, I can't seem to figure out on how to implement the thing that I would like to do. Basically, I want to retrieve the events from a google calendar with calendarID of webapps098@gmail.com. 
My current code goes something like

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_BooksService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseObjects(true);
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);

try{
    $events = $service->calendars->get('webapps098@gmail.com');
    print_r($events);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
    }
```

I am receiving the error :

> exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/webapps098@gmail.com:
>   (401) Login Required' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php:66
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(36):
>   Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(186):
>   Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_CalendarService.php(300):
>   Google_ServiceResource->__call('get', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\refreshscript.php(10):
>   Google_CalendarsServiceResource->get('webapps098@gmai...') #4 {main}

I wish anyone can help! Sorry and thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get something which needs to have an oAuth token. If you are just pulling events from public calendar, I recommend you to go for Google feeds instead for Google APIs.